# In systemverilog, a class residing in a package refer to another class defined in a global scope

Tags: system-verilog

In systemverilog, whether a class residing in a package refer to another class defined in a global scope or not?

```
class global_cls;
    int gv =4;
endclass
package my_pkg;
    class pkg_cls;
        global_cls g; //refer to the global class
    endclass
endpackage

module tb();
    my_pkg::pkg_cls a;
endmodule
```

I compiled the snippet code above by vcs and got a error message:

```
Error-[SE] Syntax error
   Following verilog source has syntax error:
       token 'global_cls’ should be a valid type. Please declare it virtual if tis is an Interface.
"tb.sv", 18: taoke is ';'
     global_cls g;
```

Comment: @hyperion007. No, a package cannot refer to anything declared outside a package except by import of another package.

Comment: @dave_59 thanks dave, how to import a global class into a package?

Comment: @toolic you are right. it's a typo, I am too careless!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there are no *globals* in SystemVerilog. There is compilation unit scope which is separate for each file you compile or each compilation step for a set of files. Any declarations you declare outside of a design entity (module/interface/package) exists in a compilation unit scope. There is no way to reference identifiers declared in one compilation unit from another compilation unit.

Second, a `package` can only reference identifiers declared within that package, or imported from another package (there is one exception for virtual interface variables)

So I suggest you create a `package globals` and put `global_cls` in that package. Then you can `import globals::*;`